# Do I have to call super.join() when subclassing threading.Thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, cherrypy

I have a subclass of `threading.thread` that is running a `cherrypy` server. My `join()` method looks like this:

```
def join(self):
    cherrypy.engine.exit()
    super(MyThread, self).join()
```

Do I have to explicitly have to call `super.join()`? What exactly does it do after I have explicitly stopped the cherrypy server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when you override a method of parent class, you should call the overridden method, unless you are absolutely sure how parent class works, and this change won't break it. That is to say more formally, inheritance represents `is-a` relationship, and your subclass still **is a** `threading.Thread`, so it should act accordingly. The topic of an inheritance contact is, in fact, quite broad, and if you're interested you may may want to start with [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Python documentation states about `threading.Thread.join([timeout])`.

> Wait until the thread terminates. This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose
>   join() method is called terminates – either normally or through an unhandled 
>   exception – or until the optional timeout occurs.

This means that if you don't call the base `join`, your subclass' `join` will no longer block the calling thread. If that is what you want, you're better just make another method like `_exitCherrypyBus` or so.